# want to train train a model based on this data which will predict if an engine will undergo a failure

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
finalfaultdata = pd.read_csv('FinalFaultData.csv')

passedmaster = pd.read_csv('PASSEDMASTER.csv')

A = pd.concat([finalfaultdata,passedmaster])

print(len(A))

train, test = train_test_split(A, test_size = 0.2,random_state = 40)

print(len(train))

print(len(test))

y = A['Verdict']

print(y)

select = ['Engine Temperature', 'Stepper Motor Position', 'MAP', 'Injection Time', 'Ignition Angle 
          Output','Water Pressure', 'Oil Pressure', 'Oil Temperature', 'Exhaust Temperature', 'Fuel 
          Pressure','Mech Errors', 'Throttle Position', 'Engine Load', 'Lambda AVG Correction', 'Intake 
          Air Temp', 'Idle Speed Controller', 'Battery Voltage', 'Lambda Correction', 'Throttle Status']
           
X = A[select]

print(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 5)

print (X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
```

what to de next to train model?

Answer (score 0):

First decide which model would be suitable for the data.Whether it should be `Logistic Regression` or `KNN` or `Random forest` etc.